# Google Cloud Logging: show lines around the matched lines

Tags: google-cloud-logging

Sometimes when searching logs by keyword or other conditions, I want to show not only the lines which match the condition, but also a few lines around them to better understand the context, similar to the `-C` flag of `grep`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

Also looking for this. What I found so far is the option to "Pin and show resource log entries" for a matched result. It will pin the entry, and then show it inline with the rest of the log

[image: Pin options once you click the icon]

Answer (score 3):

I do not think it is possible to achieve this on Google Cloud Logging.

I usually run a first query, get the timestamp of the log that I am interested in and then run a second query using **Custom time range**.

[Advanced logs queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries)